# display ads only when url+number is met

Tags: php, wordpress, function, pagination

**hello experts , i want to hide adsense ads on first page
if post url domain.com/top-10-foods  don't display
if domain.com/top-10-foods/2  display    if domain.com/top-10-foods/3  dispaly extra ....**

i've tried this code did't work

```
<?php if(!is_post_url()); ?>
  <div id="myAd"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

i want to replace this code

`<?php if(!is_post_url()); ?>`

i'll be thankfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the current page number in the context of pagination:

```php
$pageNum = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

if ($pageNum > 1) {
   // …
}
```

---

Please see [WordPress Stack exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/12377/218274) for WordPress specific questions.

Also see the docs on pagination:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/pagination/
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination